# Open source web browser for iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is there any open source web browser for iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article about some available web browsers for the iphone, none of which I believe are open source. Double check to be sure though:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/157060/first_look_new_web_browsers_for_iphone.html

You may also want to check out sunrise which is **open source**, but I don't think it's available for the iphone yet.

http://www.sunrisebrowser.com/

Other then that, I think you may be out of luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Webkit is open source. You can start with that.